# normal mapping in sceneKit editor

Tags: ios, scenekit

I'm trying to assign a normal map to my geometry object in SceneKit editor. I picked up a random rainbow image(this is my first time doing normal maps) and assign it to a normal property([image](https://www.google.si/search?q=rainbow+png&espv=2&biw=1440&bih=784&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=NaibVZ7rHoa9Ub6PhagL&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#tbm=isch&q=rainbow+gradient+png&imgrc=ykUkQEZittsfvM%3A)). This is what I got.[image]

and this is my xcode setup:[image]

This really isn't the effect I was hoping for. I imagined there will be some parts of my cube sticking out and some will be indent. There should also be visible shadow since I checked **casts Shadows** property of my spot lights.

EDIT: found this webpage for making normal maps [link](http://cpetry.github.io/NormalMap-Online/), but results are still disappointing. If you look at an appropriate angle you can see that there is no indentation and nothing sticks out of the cube. Not sure if my expectations are to high though...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)) is the direction a surface points, not how far it is perturbed from a reference point. It will only add surface detail when "lighting" is involved (including techniques like cubemap reflections).

What you're talking about is a displacement map, which combines normal and height. Parallax mapping is the optimal mix, between normal mapping and displacement mapping, for today's hardware.

Comment: Okay thanks! How do I implement parallax mapping in SceneKit? Are API's already provided?

Comment: No, you'll have to do it yourself, for now. I'll do it later but it could be 2017 before I get to it.

Comment: If you have any experience with it, could you please give me a starting point. Don't really know where to start and what to learn.

Comment: Check out the ["Projection of Bumpy Surfaces" article](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming) in the environment of your choice. I learned in Unity. That will get you a single iteration. If you need help with more iterations, post the Scene Kit project somewhere, and if you've written the beginnings, in Metal, I'll help you out. I'm not interested in working with GLSL anymore, but Metal resources are currently scarce, so I give you the most useful thing I know of.